# JSONObject constructor expecting a bean does not map attributes that are in superclasses

Tags: java, json

I'm using [JSON](http://www.json.org/), the version is the one released in November second, 2009.

When I try to use the JSONObject constructor that expects a bean, the only attributes mapped are the ones that are declared in the class itself, the ones that are declared in superclasses are not.

I downloaded the current version of [JSONObject source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java) and I checked that this issue does not occur in this version.

Does anyone know if this is a known bug in the version that I'm using? Plus, does anyone know where can I find the source code of this release?

**EDIT: The source code as requested**

```
public class Box {

    double width;
    double height;
    double depth;

    Box(final double w, final double h, final double d) {
       this.width = w;
       this.height = h;
       this.depth = d;
    }

    public void getVolume() {
       System.out.println("Volume is : " + (width * height * depth));
    }
}

public class MatchBox extends Box {

    private double weight;

    MatchBox(final double w, final double h, final double d, final double m) {
        super(w, h, d);
        weight = m;
    }
}
```

The hierarchy of the classes is something like that. Using this example, only the weight attribute is mapped, width, height and depth are not.

Comment: Can you post your class hierarchy? Are all the fields you want to be serialized visible?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis example source code provided.

Comment: I see what you mean. The current source is [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java), but I can only see the master branch.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's the version that I linked when I gave the [JSONObject source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java). I can't find the source of the version that I'm using, I already emailed the author and I'm expecting news from him.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you want to use the old version?

Comment: The system is as old as the library version and I'm not allowed to replace the version of the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.json%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json%22), the version released in 2009 does not have sources available, but the one from 2008 is certainly available.

Looking at the source, there's *two* versions of the constructor that takes a bean:

```
JSONObject(Object bean) { ... }
```

and

```
JSONObject(Object bean, boolean includeSuperClass) { ... }
```

I'm guessing you can surmise what `includeSuperClass` is for.

The first, single argument version is not scanning the superclass. The 2013 release is changed to where that is the default behavior and the second version of the constructor was eliminated.

Comment: I contacted the author and he said that he does not have the sources of the release I'm using and that he does not recommed using any other version than the current. Besides he does not know if this was a known bug. Your solution works pretty well for me, however it's good to say that in these earlier versions this constructor get the class or declaring class as an attribute too. I don't need this information and sure makes my response heavier, still this solutions is better than copy/paste the current version since I'm not allowed to replace these versions.